# Maximum number of items in a windows treeview control? Ballpark?

Tags: treeview

MSDN Says:

> A tree-view control uses memory that
>   is allocated from the heap of the
>   process that creates the tree-view
>   control. The maximum number of items
>   in a tree view is based on the amount
>   of memory that is available in the
>   heap.

So, anecdotally or otherwise, can someone give me a ballpark of what this means?  I expect the stuff I'm doing in a treeview will be limited to < 1000 items for most cases but in some cases closer to 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly as it says, the addition of treeview nodes will consume memory (reference objects that are placed on the heap) and the more you add the more it will consume. For your particular circumstance approx 10,000 I dont think memory will be a great issue for most modern day computers.

With large trees the best way I have found to deal with the loading of the tree is to load a nodes children only when the user expands the node - Loading on demand. This will save loading too many unnecessary nodes and hence reduce the amount of memory required.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some (limited) info about tree view memory usage and how to minimize it in this Knowledge Base article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130697

(Note the info about 40 bytes is probably valid for 32-bit application, for 64-bit it is probably a bit more.)

Comment: This article can now be found in the knowledge base archive: https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/130697